# Does a contraction converging in power series necessarily lead to the operator being a proper contraction?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, contraction-operator

I was recently met with this in my functional analysis class on which I am stuck:

> Let $ \mathbb{H} $ be a Hilbert space and let T be  a contraction operator on  $ \mathbb{H} $ (meaning $ ||T|| \leq 1 $ in the operator norm) . We are given these three conditions on T:
>
> 1. $ \forall h \in \mathbb{H} $ we have the convergence in norm $ T^n \to 0 $.
> 2. $ \forall h \in \mathbb{H} $ we have the convergence in norm $ T^{*n} \to 0 $.
>
> And we are asked to determine which (if any) of these conditions necessarily leads to the property that for all $ h \in \mathbb{H} $ we have $ ||Th || < ||h|| $ ?

Now I do not really know how exactly to approach this as I only know the operator norm of an operator and its adjoint are equal but nothing else. I tried giving it a go but got nothing. I would certainly appreciate the much needed help on this. Thanks all helpers.

Comment: $\|T\| \le 1$ hence $\|T h\| \le \|h\|$. suppose that for some $h$ : $\|T h\| = \|h\|$, does it follow that $\|T^n\| \not\to 0$ ? and do you know the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) ?

Comment: so the answer is no, consider the $2 \times 2$ matrix $M$ such that $M e_1 = e_2$ but $M e_2  =(1-\epsilon) e_1$, then $\|M e_1 \| = 1$ but $\|M^2\| < 1$ hence $\|M^n\| \to 0$. but the answer is yes if the operator is supposed self-adjoint ! because in that case $\|Th\| = \|h\|$ and $\|T\| =1$ means that $h$ is an eigenvector of $T$, i.e. $T h = e^{i \theta} h$ hence $\|T^n\| = 1$ for every $n$.

Comment: @user1952009 : Thank you this is clear to me now but you said if the T is self adjoint in which case I understand the reasoning but can you please tell me does condition 3 (as opposed to self-adjoitness) lead to the strict inequality $ ||Th|| < ||h|| $ hold? As I understand from you that only one of the convergences  $ T^n \to 0 $, $ T^{*n} \to 0 $ holds

Comment: try yourself creating a counter-example matrix

Comment: @user1952009 : Could you please provide me with a hint for doing this?